# How to print submatrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to plot out this matrix :

```
11 12 13 14  0  0 
0  22 23  0  0  0 
0  0  33 34 35 36 
0  0  0  44 45  0 
0  0  0   0  0 56 
0  0  0   0  0 66
```

in this way :

```
11 12
0  22

13 14
23  0

0  0 
0  0 

0  0
0  0 

23  0
33 34

35 36
45  0

0  0
0  0

0  0
0  0

0 56 
0 66
```

but I'm not figure out how to do !
I'm able just to plot the first sub-block using :

```
 for(auto i=0; i < sz ; i++ )
      {
           for(auto j=0 ; j < sz ; j++)
           {
               {
                  std::cout << dense[i][j] << ' ' ;
               }   
           }
           std::cout << std::endl;
      }
```

- Where sz=2

But then I don't have idea how to proceed ! the matrix is stored in a vector>

in this way I still got a wrong result :

```
 for(auto k=0; k < bsz ; k++)
      {
        for(auto i=k; i < sz+k ; i++ )
        {
           for(auto j=k ; j < sz+k ; j++)
           {
               {
                  std::cout << dense[i][j] << ' ' ;
               }   
           }
           std::cout << std::endl;
       }
      }
```

- where `bbz = sz*sz` ;

whit the above code I got :

```
11 12 
0 22 

22 23 
0 33 

33 34 
0 44 

44 45 
0 0
```

ok Sorry for the fool post .. I've solved ...

```
 for(auto w=0; w<= bsz ; w+=2)
     {
      for(auto k=0; k <= bsz ; k+=2)
      {
        for(auto i=w; i < sz+w ; i++ )
        {
           for(auto j=k ; j < sz+k ; j++)
           {
               {
                  std::cout << dense[i][j] << ' ' ;
               }   
           }
           std::cout<< std::endl;
       }
       std::cout << std::endl;
      } 
    }
}
```

Now I want stored this block if they are different form all zero ! for doing this I wrote the code suggest by @Jodocus in this way :

```
 for(std::size_t i = 0; i < dense.size() / sz ; i++)
    {    
        auto rowCount =0;
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < dense[i].size() / sz ; j++)
        {
            if(validate_block(dense,i,j))
            {     

                  std::cout << "*" << j+1 << std::endl;
                  aj_.push_back(j*sz+1);
                  print_block(dense, i, j);
                  std::cout << '\n';
                  rowCount ++ ;
            }      

        }
        ai_[i+1] = ai_[i] + rowCount ;
     }
```

using

```
template <typename T,std::size_t sz>
auto constexpr BCSRmatrix<T,sz>::print_block(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& dense,
                                                       std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const noexcept
{   
   for(std::size_t m = i * sz ; m < sz * (i + 1); ++m) {
      for(std::size_t n = j * sz ; n < sz * (j + 1); ++n)
                  std::cout << dense[m][n] << ' ';
      std::cout << '\n';
   }
}


template <typename T,std::size_t sz>
auto constexpr BCSRmatrix<T,sz>::validate_block(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& dense,
                                                       std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const noexcept
{   
   for(std::size_t m = i * sz ; m < sz * (i + 1); ++m)
   {
      for(std::size_t n = j * sz ; n < sz * (j + 1); ++n)
      {
            if(dense[m][n] != 0) return true;
      }
      return false ;
   }
}
```

don't care about the vector ai_ and aj_ it is just for my final routine ! 
could you tell me why the block 
`0 0 
67 0`
of this

```
matrix = BCSRmatrix<int,2> bbcsr2 = {{11,12,0,0,0,0,0,0} ,{0,22,0,0,0,0,0,0} ,{31,32,33,0,0,0,0,0},
                              {41,42,43,44,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,55,56,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,66,67,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,77,78},{0,0,0,0,0,0,87,88}};
```

doesn't pass the check ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do each block of four in the body of the inner loop, and stride by 2

```
for(auto i=0; i < dense.size() ; i+=2 )
{
    for(auto j=0 ; j < dense[i].size() ; j+=2 )
    {
        {
            std::cout << dense[i  ][j  ] << ' ' ;
            std::cout << dense[i  ][j+1] << ' ' ;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << dense[i+1][j  ] << ' ' ;
            std::cout << dense[i+1][j+1] << ' ' ;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job on figuring it out yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a very analogous way by working with multiples of the block size as index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// print the (i,j)-th block
template <typename T>
void print_block(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& dense, std::size_t block_size, std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {   
   for(std::size_t m = i * block_size; m < block_size * (i + 1); ++m) {
      for(std::size_t n = j * block_size; n < block_size * (j + 1); ++n)
         std::cout << dense[m][n] << ' ';
      std::cout << '\n';
   }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> dense = { 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 0, 4, 3, 2 },
        { 4, 2, 1, 1 },
        { 9, 0, 8, 1 }
    };
    const std::size_t block_size = 2;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < dense.size() / block_size; ++i)
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < dense[i].size() / block_size; ++j) {
            print_block(dense, block_size, i, j);
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
}
```

Comment: no @Jodocus ! your way is very very interesting .. but have some bug ! check for example what i wrote at the end of the code !

Comment: @Drudoxlebowsky This is a totally different question from your original one. I cannot reproduce your bug, my code produces the right results: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Mc0KFpry6yFeCxMR

Answer (score 0):

First define a reference point for yourself. Here, even rows and even columns could be your reference points. Then, use an extra array to print any pattern that you need. This way, with only changing your pattern values you can output any shape and not just a block.

```
int pattern[2][4] = {
{0, +1, 0, +1},
{0, 0, +1, +1}
};

for(int i = 0; i < sz; i+=2){
    for(int j = 0; j < sz; j+=2){
        for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){//size of pattern
            int new_i = i + pattern[0][k];
            int new_j = j + pattern[1][k];

            if(new_i >= sz || new_j >= sz)
                break;
            std::cout << arr[new_i][new_j] << " ";
            if(k == 1) std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```